# Qt - How to reduce the "bundled" size?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I decided to try programming with Qt since I wanted to make a GUI application in the language my application is natively written in.  I downloaded Qt, watched a few tutorials, and made a simple Hello World application.  When I tried to show my friend, however, he was complaining about missing DLLs.  Fast foward and eventually I ended up finding a tool that automatically included all of the dependencies that Qt needed to function.

So my question:

[image]

Do I really need to include all of this when I distribute my application? Is this the price I pay for not using C# and calling my application's functions through a DLL?  The actual application I'm writing only compiles to about 100kb, do I really need to include over 44x that in dependencies?

Comment: You do realize the .Net Framework is a lot larger than that, but it has to be installed too. Try running a C# application without the .Net framework and then find all the dependencies for that.

Comment: You can however get rid of some of the dependencies, like icu, by recompiling Qt with `-no-icu`. AFAIK, icu is only used for QtWebkit module.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Most people already have the .Net framework installed.  If they don't then it's usually not too much to ask to have them install it.  With this, however, I am forced to distribute all of these files with a single application.  That is my primary complaint.  I've managed to whittle down how much it actually requires that I distribute, but it's still pretty massive.

Comment: These days distributing 100 files is as easy as distributing 2. As long as they all fit on the floppy.

Comment: "all of this junk" That *junk* contains 99% of your application's code...

Comment: @cmannett85: I guess someone found the harsh words like "junk", etc, unacceptable. Some people are picky about those. One could also consider it as primarily opinion based to be fair. I gave a +1 to correct that as I think it is important to document that Qt is huge. Edit: the question as well as my answer also got another downvote, so do not worry about those too much. ;-)

Comment: I'm not dissing Qt in any way, I love working with it.  It just seemed silly to me that a simple Hello World dialog application required me to send all of that stuff.  Usually when I think something seems ridiculous, I'm probably doing it wrong, so I thought I'd ask you guys.

Comment: @hopeless_nerd: there are many fan boys who not like valid critics. You either string your sentence together in a nice way, or do not care about them. They do not matter much. ^_^

Comment: @lpapp Don't worry I shall.  Just waiting a bit to see if anyone else has any other input to contribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in short, your observation is correct. Qt is not the smallest framework possible for GUI purposes.

Even the QtCore library is getting 4-5 MB these days, let alone the rest like QtGUI, especially if you use QtWidgets, etc.

If you are really into something smaller, you can look for alternatives frameworks that are smaller. I personally prefer fltk, although I had to adjust it to my needs to be usable with framebuffers. That is probably not on your radar, though.

One thing that you could also look into is the feature system established in Qt. That means you can turn features off that you are not planning to use. The disclaimer goes that you are on your own should you decide to go down that way.

Some people think that static linking will gain you much, too. I have experimented with that quite a bit in the past, but while it had not come with huge improvements, it did come with these drawbacks:

- You need to redeploy your application whenever you would like to update Qt. This is not a corner case, obviously, since it is nice to get bug fixes, just for one of those.
- Even if you gain a small bit of size improvement, you will lose that when you start deploying multiple Qt applications.
- You can easily get into legal troubles with that, especially if you are writing proprietary software, which is again not corner case.
- It is not that straight-forward to link statically under all circumstances.

Therefore, it is better to use the feature system established for this very purpose in Qt.

Having said that, there are even bigger frameworks for this purpose just to scare you off a bit. Still, Qt is not something that you will put onto a 8 bit microcontroller with very limited flash and ram.

So my advice is either get used to the status quo or escape.

Answer (score 2):

You can compile Qt statically, then when you link against the static libraries your resulting execurable will both be:

- self contained, no need for dll's
- much smaller

Compiling Qt statically takes a long time. You also have to consider the license for Qt if you statically link if for commercial purposes.

Comment: I fail to see how this helps the OP. Static linking will not automagically crop features off! The OP's problem does not seem to be with the automated tool to be run as it does not matter how many files you distribute. The OP's valid concern is with that Qt is a huge beast.

Comment: @lpapp: DLLs contain all exported functions and all functions used by any of the exports.  When statically linking, the linker will keep just the functions odr-used by the program and throw away the rest.  Of course, this may not correspond to what is actually used by the program, if there's some registration table that all widgets get added into, needed or not.

Comment: @Ben: see my answer for details.